# Masstransit RabbitMq Request/Response cannot create auto-delete exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

We are trying to implement a request/response scenario where the messages will be deleted server(consumer) is down. We start with no exchanges / queues in the rabbit mq installation.

There is a server which creates its own exchange / queue and we want this to be `auto-delete=true`.

In case the server is up before the client, the exchange is created with the correct configuration. But when the client is up we get this error:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for exchange 'simple_request' in vhost '****': received 'false' but current is 'true'", classId=40, methodId=10, cause=

In case the client is up first, and tries to send a message an exchange is created with the queue name that we have defined but it is not `auto-delete=true` which results to error:

> RabbitMQ receive transport failed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for exchange 'simple_request' in vhost '****': received 'true' but current is 'false'", classId=40, methodId=10, cause=RabbitMQ receive transport failed: The supervisor is stopping, no additional scopes can be created

when the server is eventually started.

How do we implement auto-delete queues in a request response scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the URI in your client for the service queue to include query string parameters so that the queue is created properly.

`rabbitmq://host/vhost/queue?autodelete=true&durable=false`

Note I included `durable=false` but that's only if you're using a non-durable queue and I wanted to be complete.

Comment: Is this still the way to do this in 2021? I'd like to see some (broker agnostic) MT API on SendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint() to control this behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Well, now you can use `queue:queue-name?autodelete=true&durable=false`, but otherwise, yes it's the same.

Comment: Thanks! Is something like this also possible for Azure Service Bus? I have to support both. Ultimately I would like to have a queue auto-delete after a set timeout, which should be possible on both brokers. I just can't seem to find the MassTransit way to achieve this.